# Django admin actions based on custom conditions

Tags: django, admin

I have a user model with fields like user_name, email and created_on. I tried the following code to export the user data into csv format

Using the following code I am able to download the selected user data. Is it possible to download the user list on the basis of the time period (created_on) by making use of this function ?

```
def export_as_csv(self, request, queryset):
   meta = self.model._meta
   field_names = [field.name for field in meta.fields]
   response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}.csv'.format(meta)
   writer = csv.writer(response)
   writer.writerow(["first_name", "email", "created_on"])
   for obj in queryset:
       row = writer.writerow([obj.first_name, obj.email, obj.created_on)
   return response


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [export_as_csv]
    list_display = ('created_on','email', 'first_name')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its possible.
you can query from selected queryset to have greater/less:

```
import datetime
queryset.filter(created_on__gt=datetime.datetime.now())
```

but i see no reason to do it .. i think better idea is to use some third party library like:
https://pypi.org/project/django-admin-rangefilter/

then filter your records in admin list and then use your function without changes